# How do I get the name of the project/assembly that called a class library from within the class library when a method logs an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, class-library

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask before having to make dozens of changes to my code. Note that the class library is part of a nuget package and the project for it IS NOT included in ASP.NET Core Web project that calls it.

We use custom nuget packages fairly extensively to break up common pieces of code needed by various ASP.NET Core 6 web projects. One queries the database for Employee Information. One has utility classes that do "things". Every method in these nuget packages perform their own exception handling which logs exceptions and associated details to the database.

The issue is that the log might look like this:

```
Location: Namespace.Employee -> EmpClass.cs --> methodName(parameter)
```

Well we now have several projects that use these nuget packages, but from the error logged, it's not possible to know what project had the error. We just know the nuget package, which means any of the live projects could have errored.

The design of these helper classes has them as static classes, which means, I'd have to modify all of their methods to include a parameter calling code can use to pass in the project name. At best, this would duplicate dozens of methods. At worst, it'd break many projects (if I just modified existing methods). We are, of course, versioning our packages so we wouldn't have to fix this in anything until a project needs to update to the latest version.

I've tried including something like this along with the error message within the nuget package, but it just points to the nuget package dll as the calling assembly...which it is, I suppose.

```
            string callingAssembly = "Calling Assembly Not Available";
            if( Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() != null )
            {
                callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().ToString();
            }
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm not thinking it is with our current setup.

Given this setup, what would you recommend as a better way to refactor (in abstract terms) things to allow making a change such as this easier in the future?

**ADDED CODE EXAMPLE**

```
//User info is a class library from a nuget package. The dll name is Intranet.Users.
UserInfo crashTest = UserInfo.GetUser(555);

Inside of Intranet.Users is User.cs with the method 

public static UserInfo GetUser(int UserId)
{

            try
            {
                //Code the queries the database for a user with UserId = 555
                
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string callingAssembly = "Calling Assembly Not Available";
                if( Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() != null )
                {
                    callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().ToString();
                }

                //The 'Logging' class is actually from the Intranet.Utilities nuget package class library used by this 
                //library. It logs the error information to the database.
                Logging.LogError(ex, "Intranet.Users > Users.cs > GetUser(UserId)", "UserId = " + UserId.ToString() +  $" in {callingAssembly}" );
            }

}
```

The value of `callingAssembly` is "Intranet.Users, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

Comment: Don't you log the call stack? This seems to be a x-y question to me.

Comment: ^^ https://xyproblem.info/ What logging framework is in use? And maybe also share a code example of how you are logging an exception.

Comment: Just read what an xy problem is. Pretty sure this isn't that. We don't have an external logging framework. We just use a static class that takes a set of parameters and writes the data to a database table. The call stack doesn't include anything outside of the nuget package's library because the error is trapped within the class library so that's it's origin. The issue is I need to include the application that called the class library as part of the information the error logging does, but the methods don't have a parameter specified for that.

Comment: _"We just use a static class that takes a set of parameters and writes the data to a database table"_ - That's what I feared. Makes things so much more complicated. My first suggestion would be not to roll your own.

Comment: @Fildor Yeah it's an issue I'm only just now seeing the problem with. If it was a concrete class, we could add the project name as part of a constructor and wouldn't have to tweak the method parameters. Can you recommend another solution? I really am all ears here.

Comment: I really don't know enough about your codebase to suggest anything actually useful. Dragging along caller names cannot be the solution, though. I wonder how you cap those call stacks.

Comment: Just so we are talking about the same thing: I am talking about the output here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4uWQa

Comment: Haha, my own example got me to it: You are logging too early! Just have the exception bubble up. => https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNTY1s

Comment: Ah...I guess I see the point in that. I added some clarifying code to the question.

Comment: Oh yes. That's really bad. That shouldn't be static. It has sideeffects. But well, it is what it is, I guess you did not design it.

Comment: But what happens to the call? You catch and log the exception but you do not actually _handle_ it. I guess you are returning something in the exception case? Or null? (* hoping for rethrow ... )

Comment: Unfortunately, the methods' return values don't factor in returning more details in case an error occurs. I just wasn't forward thinking enough in this case it seems. I'm not rethrowing the error either.

Comment: Yes, but I mean, you need to return _someting_. Otherwise it's not valid syntax. "Some Paths do not return a value" ... right?

Comment: Oh it does return an object. The UserInfo object in this case. There's just not a property to contain error information. The class library isn't letting the error bubble up either.

Comment: Sounds like that needs to be adjusted to return an UnableToLoadUser result or something like that. Or keep letting that exception bubble up to some place where you can do something about it.